# How to do proper app slicing for data files in iOS?

Tags: ios, app-thinning

I have data file **A** for iPad 2 and iPad 3. 
And another data file **B** for iPad 4 and upper.

It is packed data for textures in my special way to load it much faster.
I've seen that Asset Catalogs has option Metal 1v2, but does it work for iPad 2/3/4 ?

How to properly configure this in Asset Catalog? 
Does anybody found the way?